# FusedLocationClient troubleshooting Out of Service Scenario

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am currently able to receive location updates while service is available, but if service is not available I need to get a response so that I can call another method to handle this situation. From what I've gathered is that these are the only two methods onLocationResult() and onLocationAvailability() I have to work with in terms of using the requestLocationUpdates(). The responses I've gotten from onLocationAvailabilty do not seem to be very accurate and if I am actually out of service this method might not be called by the fusedLocationClient for some time. My other issue is that the onLocationResult does not seem to let me know if there is not a result, which would be highly useful in my case. What is the best way to know if the fusedLocationClient can not find a location or is currently out of service? locationAvailability.isLocationAvailable() tends to give me the unreliable answer of being false even when I do have service...

```
    mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, callback = new LocationCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                    // do work here
                    onLocationChanged(locationResult.getLastLocation());}

                @Override
                public void onLocationAvailability(LocationAvailability locationAvailability) {

                }
            }, Looper.myLooper());
}
```

Comment: Can you post logcat here? Also, do you have a clean project where you can reproduce this?

Comment: Sorry I am unable to provide project code for this.

Answer (score 0):

So best solution that I found was to implement a LocationListener and utilize the onStatusChanged() method which gives a response when the user is steps out of service and again when they step back into service.